# Getting list.js filter function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, list.js

I cannot seem to get the List.js filter function to work. And the documentation for List.js leaves a lot to be desired as a newbie developer.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="lessons">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="filter-series">James</button>
  <ul class="list">
    {% for lesson in lessons %}
    <li>
      <h4 class="date" style="float:right;">{{lesson.date}}</h4>
      <h4 class="series">{{lesson.series}} ({{lesson.lesson_type}})</h4>
      <div style="float:clear;"></div>
        <h3 style="font-size:1.5em; color:#f68026; text-transform:uppercase;" class="title">{{lesson.title}}</h3>
        <p></p>
        <p>{{lesson.info}}</p>
        {% if lesson.url != "" %}
        <audio controls preload="none">
          <source src="{{lesson.url}}" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        {% endif %}
        <p>
        {% if lesson.manuscript != none  %}[<a href="{{lesson.manuscript}}">Manuscript</a>]{% endif %}
        {% if lesson.handout != none %} [<a href="{{lesson.handout}}">Handout</a>]{% endif %}
        {% if lesson.ppt != none %} [<a href="{{lesson.ppt}}">PPT</a>
        {% endif %}
        </p>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- list.js script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'series', 'date']
  };

  var featureList = new List('lessons', options);

  $('#filter-series').on('click',function(){
    var $text = $(this).text();
    if($(this).hasClass( 'selected' )){
      featureList.filter();
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      featureList.filter(function(item) {
        return (item.values().series == $text);
      });
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });

});

//-->
</script>
```

You can see what happens [here](http://jimbrink.org/lessons). Basically, when I hit the "James" button, nothing happens. I have searched StackOverflow looking for an answer, but I cannot get it to work.

I would eventually like to have a drop-down menu with all the lesson series for people to filter through. But just getting this one should teach me enough about list.js to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the button setup with the *class* `filter-series`.  But you are using an *id* selector.

The correct selector would be:

```
$('.filter-series').on('click', function() { ...
```

Comment: Crap! And I checked that several times but just kept letting my brain slip to the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome debugger (F12 in Chrome if you are not sure how to get there) tells you the problem:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

You have one too many closing characters:

```
});
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var options = {
        valueNames: ['series', 'date']
    };

    var featureList = new List('lessons', options);

    $('#filter-series').on('click', function () {
        var $text = $(this).text();
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            featureList.filter();
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            featureList.filter(function (item) {
                return (item.values().series == $text);
            });
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
    //removed });
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't recognize this! This plus the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/41352352/6880210">answer from nickles80</a>, plus my answer, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem after I took into account nickles80 and Jason Heine's answer (both of which were needed and helpful).

I had:

```
<h4 class="series">{{lesson.series}} ({{lesson.lesson_type}})</h4>
```

But the function was trying to match "James to what showed up between the h4 tags. But I had, e.g. "James (Sermon)" showing up between the tags.

So I had to change it to:

```
      <h4 class="series">{{lesson.series}}</h4>
```

That works now!